# Universal Control: How to use keyboard to switch applications across devices?

Tags: macos

Cmd+Tab works on a per-device basis rather than to re-select the previously active app.

For example, I have Slack open and being used on the iPad, and move the cursor over to the Mac via UC. Prior to clicking down, typing on the Mac continues to enter text into Slack on the iPad (great!). I can even scroll windows on the mac while typing into Slack on iPad (great!).

Upon clicking somewhere on the Mac, the keyboard focus on the iPad goes away, and now there is no longer any way to return to typing into Slack on the iPad by only using the keyboard, since Cmd+Tab only toggles through local apps on the Mac. I would have to mouse back over and click, and not just that: I have to use UC to mouse back over to the ipad and *click inside the text entry section* of the Slack app.

I greatly appreciate UC's high performance (reason to avoid using Sidecar), but the lack of consistent keyboard maps is unfortunate and something which Sidecar preserves.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, mouse cursor is the only way to switch between devices as of now.

I am using the feature to switch between my work MacbookPro and my personal Mini. I would have been great if I could switch using the keyboard. :(